# Gmail Id, phone number and clash of clans account lost

Tags: clash-of-clans

I played this account about two years back. I want to continue this account now, but I have lost my Gmail Id, my old phone, and the phone number I made the Gmail with. I managed to get a screenshot of my profile from a COC friend, so I know my player name and tag.
   Since I lost Gmail Id and the phone number too(which I could otherwise have used to find my gmail account) , I have no idea what to do. I also can't disconnect and reconnect Google play account since I'm using a new phone. 
     So is there any way I could get back my COC account with my player name, player tag and basically my player profile but no Gmail Id?(The account wasn't connected to supercell, only Gmail).
   Thanks.

Comment: This seems more relevant to your phone itself than to the game. If you had a reddit account instead of a clash of clans account it would not make a single difference in the recovery steps unless one of the accounts don't require an email account, which I doubt. This question might have a better fit on Android Enthusiasts stack exchange, but even if it was migrated there, it would probably be impossible to solve. Be lucky that you have another device to get a bit of help.

Comment: @mindstormsboi actually, there is an in-game solution for this. I'll post it in my answer.

Comment: See Supercell Support article: [I lost my village! How do I get it back?](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?s=lost-village&f=i-lost-my-village-how-do-i-get-it-back&p=web)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible!

I've had this problem as well, and luckily, Supercell has an amazing support team which will help you out.

First of all, download Clash of Clans on your new device, go to the settings and find the FAQ: go to the section named "[I lost my village! How do I get it back?](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?s=lost-village&f=i-lost-my-village-how-do-i-get-it-back&l=en&p=web)". Since you don't have your Google Play account anymore, you'll have to scroll all the way down, where you'll see this:

> I STILL DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO, HELP!
>
> Using the Village available on your device, answer "NO" to "Was this helpful?" (it's at the bottom of this FAQ). Then, contact us with the following details:
>
> Please be sure to include the following information:
>
> 1. Exact Username and Clan Name of your lost Village (or player tag if possible)
> 2. Exact Town Hall level of your lost Village
> 3. Exact XP level of your lost Village
> 4. Explain how you lost the Village
>
> For security reasons, we may need to reply with additional questions and can only recover your account once.

There you have it. I can confirm from experience that the 4 listed pieces of information are to find the village in the first place; Supercell support will ask verification questions to verify that the village belonged to you, and since it did belong to you, you should be able to answer those questions.

Do take into account that even if you follow all the required steps, recovering the village is not guaranteed.

Next time make sure you check out the FAQ ;)

Good luck!